# How correctly set the remote on a local repository to my centralized repository on a server?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, git-bash, git-remote

I have created a central repository on a Linux server following this tutorial:

http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/centralized-workflows

So basically I actually have this folder:

```
MyServer@MyUser:~/repositories/backend-central-repo.git$
```

on my server that represent my remote GIT repository.

I am connecting to this server via **SSH** using an address like: **MyServer.cloudapp.net**, the username **MyUser** and the related password.

Now on my local machine I have a local GIT repository like:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/TESTREPO (master)
```

In this repository I have committed a **test.txt** file, infact I have this commit:

```
$ git log
commit a11633549763c4cc905a721932c4c6bdc1a1091c
Author: AndreaNobili <nobili.andrea@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Oct 4 20:17:35 2016 +0200

    test
```

Then, on my local repository I have added the remote repository as origin, doing:

```
$ git remote add origin MyServer.cloudapp.net/repositories/backend-central-re
po.git$
```

Then I try to do:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/TESTREPO (master)
$ git remote -v
origin  MyServer.cloudapp.net/repositories/backend-central-repo.git$ (fetch)
origin  MyServer.cloudapp.net/repositories/backend-central-repo.git$ (push)
```

What it means? That it work fine?

Comment: It just shows the contents of your config file. Try pulling from or pushing to your remote repository to actually check that it works.

Comment: I obtain a fatal error "doesn't not appear to be a git repository", maybe the url is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "doesn't not appear to be a git repository

The ssh url for your repo should be

```
MyUser@MyServer.cloudapp.net:/home/MyUser/repositories/backend-central-repo.git
```

Try in your local repo:

```
git remote set-url origin MyUser@MyServer.cloudapp.net:/home/MyUser/repositories/backend-central-repo.git
```

Then, if your remote repo is empty, you can push your local repo to it:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: I obtain this error message:
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/TESTREPO (master)
$ git push -u origin master
ssh: connect to host sabnob.cloudapp.net port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Why? What am I missing?

Comment: @AndreaNobili first check if you can actually use ssh: ssh -T MyUser@MyServer.cloudapp.net: does it work?

Comment: @AndreaNobili if the ssh session does work, type a `ls /home/MyUser/repositories/backend-central-repo.git` to check the validity and existence of that repository path.